# removing an item from an interface based collection will not work

Tags: c#, .net, collections, interface

(FYI, Foo and Bar are Entity Framework POCO entity classes)

I would like to use this interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
 int Id { get; set; }
 string Name { get; set; }
 ICollection<IBar> IBars{ get; set; } //association with another entity
}

My implementation is as follows:

public class Foo : IFoo
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars{ get; set; }

//Interface implementation
 public ICollection<IBar> IBars
        {
            get
            {
                return Bars.Cast<IBar>().ToList();
                //or return new List<ICardInquiry>(CardsInquiries);
            }

            set
            {
                if (value is ICollection<IBar>)
                    Bars= ((ICollection<IBar>)value).Cast<Bar>().ToList();
                else
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
}
```

This implementation prevents me to remove an element from the collection:

```
IFoo iFoo = MyIFooFactory.CreateIFoo();
IBar iBar = iFooIBars.First();
iFoo.IBars.Remove(iBar);
```

This will NOT remove the element! I do understand why. The reason is my interface collection getter, which is again as follows:

```
public ICollection<IBar> IBars
        {
            get
            {
                return Bars.Cast<IBar>().ToList();
                //or return new List<ICardInquiry>(CardsInquiries);
            }
          ...
         }
```

IBars returns a new list so the element is removed from the returned list and not from the original collection (Bars).

How can I get out of this situation? I really don't want IFoo to know about Bar and to only manimpulate IBar.

Comment: `if (value is ICollection<IBar>)` that is a useless check. It's already enforced by the property type.

Comment: You're creating a new collection filled with the same elements when you call `.ToList()`

Comment: I assume `Bar` implements interface `IBar`? since you do not show the source code of `Bar`. It is not a complete and verifiable example.

Comment: Yes Bar does implement interface IBar

Comment: I question your goal here. `ICollection<T>` allows adding of elements, do you allow the caller to add anything that implements `IBar`? If so, why not make the internal collection out of IBar as well? Do you treat Bar objects different from other objects implementing IBar?

Comment: Foo and Bar are my current model entities.
I might soon have other model implementations that will also implement IBar and IFoo differently.
So I want a DbContext that manipulates IFoo and IBar.
So Foo will only manipulate Bar objects.
Bu I will soon have some Foo2 objects manipulating Bar2 objects.
This is what I try to anticipae with the interace abstraction.